# Template compilation error - standard or not?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

```
template<int k>
void foo()
{
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int k = 1000;
    foo<k>();
    return 0;
}
```

which doesn't compile, but if I declare `k` as `const`, it does:

```
template<int k>
void foo()
{
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int k = 1000;
    foo<k>();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I see the logic behind why in the first case it doesn't compile and in the second it does, but is this specified by the standard?

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error   1   error C2971: 'foo' : template parameter 'k' : 'k' : a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument
```

which isn't exactly clear, since `k` is a local variable also in the case it's `const`... right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

§14.3.2.1 says [abridged]:

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>   — an integral *constant-expression* of integral or enumeration type;

And §5.19.1 says [abridged, emphasis mine]:

> An *integral constant-expression* can involve only literals, enumerators, **const variables or static data members of integral or enumeration types initialized with constant expressions**...

Your second definition of `k` satisfies this, so it's allowed to be used as an ICE for the template argument.

The error is slightly misleading in that "a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument" is true *in general*, but with certain restrictions it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

Per the standard, 14.3.2, this must be a constant expression:

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>   — **an integral constant-expression of integral or enumeration type**; or
>   — the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
>   — the address of an object or function with external linkage, including function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed as & id-expression where the & is optional if the name refers to a function or array, or if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference;
>   or
>   — a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1 .

GCC 4.6.2 gives a slightly more comprehensible error:

> error: ‘k’ cannot appear in a constant-expression

Comment: You didn't specify why `k` works in one but not the other, which was the meat of the question.

Comment: See the section I bolded. The standard says the expression must be constant.

Comment: But I repeat myself: you don't address why `k` is usable or not.

Comment: I can explain it to you, but I can't understand it for you. I don't know how I can make it clearer than I already have. It's because the standard says the expression must be constant.

Comment: Look at my answer, note the second half.

Comment: I have no idea what your point is, honestly. Yes, you cited the standard for the fairly obvious point that a const variable is a constant expression. What do you want me to do? Give you a medal?

Comment: No. As I said in my *first* comment, the entire point of his question to find out *why* one `k` works and one doesn't. You managed to get half-way there, and I was hoping you'd simply agree and edit in the remaining information so I could delete my answer, but instead you chose to be arrogant and stubborn. Cheers.

Comment: If you genuinely think that point is not totally obvious, then your answer is complete and mine is not. Honestly, I think it's needless clutter.

Comment: To quote the question: "Now, I see the logic behind why in the first case it doesn't compile and in the second it does, **but is this specified by the standard**?" I'm not sure how much clearer this can be said: if he wanted to substitute "obvious" points into his reasoning, he wouldn't ask the question in the first place, since he'd already done that. He's asking for the note-so-obvious standard-based justification.

Answer (score 2):

No. Const values can be evaluated on compilation time when compilator tries to expand templates to final form. So execution-time values can't be arguments for templates, but always you can set reference to variable as template argument

```
template<int& k>
void foo()
{
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int k = 1000;
    foo<k>();
    return 0;
}
```